# Run part of the test suite only in specific environment in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I have a test suite that is run in 4 environments: `local`, `staging`, `production` and let's say `custom` using the `env` variable. I would like to have some tests to be run only on `production`, some test only on `staging`, how to flag specific `describe`/test/test file to be able to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the root of your Cypress project, create a `cypress.json` and add your production url. For example:

```
{
  "baseUrl": `https://www.production.com`,
}
```

Now, if you don't pass any environment variables when you run tests `cypress run`, your tests will run against production.

You can also set different baseUrl's to run against. For example:

```
CYPRESS_BASE_URL=https://www.development.com cypress run
```

You can then retrieve the baseUrl in your tests:

```
const isProd = Cypress.config().baseUrl === "https://www.production.com";
const isDev = Cypress.config().baseUrl === "https://www.development.com";
const isStaging = Cypress.config().baseUrl === "https://www.staging.com";
const isCustom = Cypress.config().baseUrl === "https://www.custom.com";
```

There are different ways to structure it from here depending on your test set up. Either pass a `skip` argument to your tests depending on the above variables, or set up your test runner to skip/run entire batches of tests by environment:

```
function runTests() {
    if (isDev) {
        runDevTests()
    }
    if (isStaging) {
        runStagingTests()
    }
    if (isProd) {
        runStagingTests()
    }
    if (isCustom) {
        runCustomTests()
    }
}
```